Retrieve list of most frequent Opponents with Winrate efficiently
I have a website for showing matches of a RTS game.
One use cases is to show a list with the most frequent opponents of a player. In this list I want to show the number of games the player played against each of the opponents and the winrate in %.
PostgreSQL 14.13
Table structure:
(I have included the match table for better understanding. It is not used in the query though)
create table public.match (
  match_id integer primary key not null,
  started timestamp(3) without time zone,
  ...
);
create index "IDX_e7b6cfca8139b9aa85880aab9e" on match using btree (started);

create table public.player (
  match_id integer not null,
  profile_id integer not null,
  slot smallint not null,
  started timestamp(3) without time zone,
  won boolean,
  ...,

  primary key (match_id, profile_id, slot),

  foreign key (match_id) references public.match (match_id)
  match simple on update cascade on delete restrict,
  foreign key (profile_id) references public.profile (profile_id)
  match simple on update cascade on delete restrict
);
create index player_profile_id_started_match_id on player using btree (profile_id, started, match_id);
create index idx_player_match_id_profile_id_won_50 on player using btree (match_id, profile_id, won);

The match table has 50 million records. The player table 200 million records.
There are about 50000 matches with 4 players on average added per day to the database.
The tables currently contain data for the last 3 years. The match table has relation_size 6 GB and total_relation_size 12 GB. The player table 15 GB and 37 GB.
I use the following query to get the top 10 most frequent opponents:
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT p2.profile_id, COUNT(*) as games
FROM player as p
JOIN player as p2 ON p2.match_id = p.match_id
WHERE p.profile_id = 271202 AND p2.profile_id != p.profile_id
GROUP BY p2.profile_id
ORDER BY games desc
LIMIT 10;

I have created the index idx_player_match_id_profile_id_won_50 on player using btree (match_id, profile_id, won) which results in Index Only Scans but the query still takes 800ms:
Limit  (cost=57091.67..57091.69 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=805.865..805.868 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=57091.67..57452.93 rows=144504 width=12) (actual time=805.864..805.866 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=49071.44..53968.99 rows=144504 width=12) (actual time=805.206..805.678 rows=1785 loops=1)
              Group Key: p2.profile_id
              Planned Partitions: 4  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1809kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..24213.39 rows=441921 width=4) (actual time=0.642..799.779 rows=8156 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using player_profile_id_started_match_id on player p  (cost=0.57..54.76 rows=1268 width=8) (actual time=0.416..3.299 rows=3428 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (profile_id = 271202)
                          Heap Fetches: 2
                    ->  Index Only Scan using idx_player_match_id_profile_id_won_50 on player p2  (cost=0.57..15.56 rows=349 width=8) (actual time=0.229..0.231 rows=2 loops=3428)
                          Index Cond: (match_id = p.match_id)
                          Filter: (profile_id <> p.profile_id)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                          Heap Fetches: 4
Planning Time: 0.448 ms
Execution Time: 806.006 ms

If I understand correctly the DB fetches all 3428 player entries for the id 271202 in 4ms and then loops over all these to get the opponents in 3428*0.2ms ~ 700ms.
Is there any optimization possible?
My idea is to reduce the scope to the matches in the last 3 months / the last year to reduce the query time. But I want to avoid that if it's possible.
